# What is the equivalent operator to `in` in the `operator` module?

Tags: python

The module `operator` offers equivalent functions for almost all standard operations.

I have not been able to find the equivalent for the `in` (`if x in y:`) operator.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that it literally says *"Return the outcome of the test `b in a`"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I looked over that list many times and even searched for ` in ` but somehow completely overlooked that entry....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [`operator.contains`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.contains):

```
if x in y:
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if operator.contains(y, x): # Note the reversed operand!
```

Answer (score 3):

In the python data model, the `in` operator is implemented via the [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) hook.  Operator follows suit so the method is [`operator.contains`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.contains).